# What's wrong with HCI applet downloading on smart card?

Tags: applet, nfc, smartcard

I have an SWP supported smart card. I want to install an HCI applet (i.e. Host Controller Interface applet) to use over NFC in an NFC supported mobile phone.

I have written a sample applet and compiled successfully, and now I'm ready to download and install this applet on my smart card (USIM).

Unfortunately, when trying to download this applet on my sim, I get the following error:

[image]

I'm using PyApduTool for this purpose. where am I wrong or am I missing something? Is there any prerequisites or configuration needed?

Comment: Code "69 85" means "Conditions of use not satisfied", e.g. authentication required. You mentioned the smart card is a USIM. Is this a a free USIM or one of a mobile network operator? If it is the latter only the MNO can modify the USIM.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for answering. It's a free USIM since I have EncKey DecKey and MacKey. All other applets are installed successfully but applets using SimToolkit or uicc libraries become erroneous.

Comment: The at-notation on StackOverflow only works for users that were already active in the comments of this question (because the name is not unique). Hence your last comment has not reached the person you were aiming on.

Comment: @Robert Thank you for your notation.

Comment: Maybe it is worth checking out another tool which can install applets to see if there  is an error with the passes parameters or not. I'm just trying to release a newer version of GPShell (https://kaoh.github.io/globalplatform/) and would be interested in a beta tester. This a tool written in C, there are also Java based tools, whatever fits your environment better. If the error is still there: a) Is there already an applet or remaining package installed on the card? b) Does the applet requires some parameters to get installed? c) Does it need some special UICC toolkit parameters?

Answer (score 1):

- Is there already an applet or remaining package installed on the card? Use a GET STATUS call for this.
- Does the applet requires some parameters to get installed? These are some byte encoded parameters passed to the `install` method of the Java Card applet. If the HCI applet needs it, it can throw such a status word.
- Does the applet need some special UICC toolkit parameters, i.e. is it a toolkit applet? A toolkit applet is an applet being able to react on external event, i.e. in or out call, OTA, location changes of the device, providing STK menu structures,  ...

If nothing helps try it with another tool. I'm just trying to release a newer version of [GPShell](https://kaoh.github.io/globalplatform/) and would be interested in a beta tester. This a tool is written in C, there are also Java based tools, e.g. [GlobalPlatformPro](https://github.com/martinpaljak/GlobalPlatformPro) whatever fits your environment better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try GPShell to install the same applet and report the results. What do the second and third questions mean? I know some parameters for installing specific applets like NFC for allowing access to them but what does "Toolkit parameters" mean?

Comment: I added some comment for the Toolkit parameters. If you are not familiar with this it will most likely not the problem.